# \documentclass[letterpaper]{article} produces A4

Tags: paper-size

I'm trying to create an 8.5x11" document, but my system defaults to A4. Being in Canada where US letter is the norm, this is frustrating. I've tried adding

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
```

to the beginning of my document, but I still get A4. I'm on Slackware 14.1, and using `pdflatex` to generate my document.

Even this small example creates an A4 sized document:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\title{Title}
\author{Your name!}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Fun times with paper sizes}
blah blah blah...
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong with respect to declaring my paper size, and how can I set US letter to be the default on my system?

---

### Edit:

Here is the command line output:

```
$ pdflatex swe.tex 
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)
entering extended mode
(./swe.tex
LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>
Babel <v3.8d> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman, b
ahasa, basque, bulgarian, catalan, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, e
stonian, finnish, greek, icelandic, irish, italian, latin, magyar, norsk, polis
h, portuges, romanian, russian, serbian, slovak, slovene, spanish, swedish, tur
kish, ukrainian, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./swe.aux) [1{/usr/share/texmf-v
ar/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./swe.aux) )</usr/share/texmf/fonts/ty
pe1/bluesky/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/bluesky/cm/cmbx12.pfb></
usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/bluesky/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/
bluesky/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on swe.pdf (1 page, 17745 bytes).
Transcript written on swe.log.
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`.

Comment: Hi! Would you please add the output of the compilation process, from the beginning to a point where it says `<yourfilename>.aux` ? Not from the file, just from the console.

Comment: @HarishKumar That will probably work, however, it should work even without the package.

Comment: The default paper size in your tex distribution is set to `a4paper`, it seems. That is the reason.

Comment: @tohecz It depends :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` does the trick, but tohecz seems to be thinking it shouldn't be necessary. Am I reading you correctly? I'd be happy to try other options too.

Comment: You're using a quite old TeX distribution. It would be better to upgrade it. You should be able to get US Letter paper by default running `texconfig-sys paper letter` as superuser.